# R::Error in argument is not a matrix

Tags: r

I need to pick top 3 values from each column of a matrix using R and populate the values to a holder(another matrix).

While trying to do this, I am getting an error as :

```
Error in t.default(head(n = 3, rownames(trans.cosine[order(trans.cosine[,  : 
  argument is not a matrix
```

This is the R code i use:

```
recsys <- read.csv("H:/Recommender Systems/Recsys.csv") 

recsys.ibs <- (recsys[,!(names(recsys) %in% c("NAME"))])     
recsys.ibs.normalized <- normalize(recsys.ibs, byrow =  FALSE)

n <- recsys$NAME
trans <- t(recsys.ibs.normalized)
colnames(trans) <- n
trans.cosine <- cosine(trans)
write.csv(trans.cosine, "H:/Recommender Systems/cosine_similarity.csv")

recsys.neighbours <- matrix(NA, nrow=ncol(trans.cosine),ncol=3,dimnames=list(colnames(trans.cosine)))


for(i in 1:ncol(trans.cosine)) 
{
  recsys.neighbours[i,] <- (t(head(n=3,rownames(trans.cosine[order(trans.cosine[,i],decreasing=TRUE),][i]))))
}
```

I am getting the error as soon as i execute the above for loop.

I checked the vectors, they are matrix. But still i am getting the error.

```
> class(trans.cosine)
[1] "matrix"
> class(recsys.neighbours)
[1] "matrix"
```

Any help on this would be verymuch useful.

Thank you

Comment: Check each piece of the RHS of the expression.  It should be obvious where the error is.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Thanks for your suggestion. I was checking each piece of the expression as you were suggesting, and converted the "trans.cosine" to a dataframe before getting into the for loop. It is working now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not reproducible, but because you are using `[i]` you get a single number which has no rownames, so that you get

```
t(NULL)
# Error in t.default(NULL) : argument is not a matrix
```

The same could happen without the `[i]` if the matrix has no rownames. And either way, rownames returns a vector, so using `t` is not meaningful here. `head(3,` is also odd, use `[1:3]`

Comment: Next time you can try editing your original answer.  I saw no reason to delete it.